# FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist on Docker container

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, intellij-idea

I'm starting a simple postgresql container like this:

```
docker run --name postgresql -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -p 5432:5432 -d postgres:11.7-alpine
```

As I'm not specifying the username will be using the default one "**postgresq**", but when I try to create a datasource using intelliJ or a connection into a spring boot project, I'm always getting the same error:

> FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I runned the container and works, then open DBeaver-CE, check the connection and work (notice DBeaver download some packages to connect and manipulate postgres). I created a new database, add esquemas, add tables, and works... Maybe is a plugin problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, was a silly mistake, didn't notice that the PC (I got it from work) already has a running PostgreSQL server.